# define the retracement levels and extension levels in pinescript v5

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am getting syntax errors at input when defining fiblevels and extension levels.

I am fairly new to PineScript and looking for help.

```
// Define the retracement levels
fibLevels = [0, 0.236, 0.382, 0.5, 0.618, 0.786, 1]

// Define the extension levels
extLevels = [0, 0.236, 0.382, 0.5, 0.618, 0.786, 1.272, 1.618]
```

I tried the array set. but it doesn't exist in v5, and I change brackets also

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with your response. I am a beginner in script and in general coding.

Comment: If cryptic I was, then sorry I am.  I meant that a `pine-script-v5` tag exists, which you should have applied to your question.  (I have added it for you, but I was giving you a chance to do so yourself.)  It's important, when discussing matters of syntax, to tag your question appropriately so that it gets the attention of the people who can best answer it or otherwise reference it.

Comment: Please add the error message you are seeing. See [mcve] for more info